# #NAME? Error In Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error, user-defined-functions

Excel Returns an error #NAME? when I try to reference this function in a sheet.  What I am doing wrong here?

The goal of the function is to look through a list to compare a number and a name to the ones entered, and then return a string of additional information based on that name.

```
Function Cname(Name As String, Number As Integer) As String
    x = 3
    For x = 3 To x = 6857
    If Name = Worksheets("Master List").Cells(x, 2).Value Then

        If Number = Worksheets("Master List").Cells(x, 3).Value Then
            Cname = Worksheets("Master List").Cells(x, 1).Value
            End Function
        End If

    Else
        x = x + 1

    End If
End Function
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you have macros enabled? where is the code located-which workbook and which module?

Comment: The code is incorrect. I can't see `Next` for the `For` loop. And, why do you need to do `x = x + 1` when `For` does it? Do a Debug -> Compile on your code first. Also, wouldn't `VLOOKUP` be useful instead?

Comment: I do have macros enabled.  I am new to the VBA side of Excel.  I originally had a while loop instead of a For loop.  I must of missed that I needed a next.  I am not familiar with VLOOKUP, I will look into using it.   Thank you for the replies!!

Comment: @JosieP  The code is located in Module 2 of the workbook that I am trying to use the function it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDEX('Master List'!A3:A6857, MATCH(1, ('Master List'!B3:B6857="NameBeingSearched") * ('Master List'!C3:C6857=NumberBeingSearched),0))
```

Paste the above formula in a cell (where you could be using the `CName` function).
Instead of pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Does this help?

courtesy: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/306615-vlookup-multiple-criteria.html

EDIT: Using VBA

```
Function Cname(Name As String, Number As Integer) As String
    dim x as integer
    x = 3
    For x = 3 To 6857
       If Name = Worksheets("Master List").Cells(x, 2).Value Then
          If Number = Worksheets("Master List").Cells(x, 3).Value Then
             Cname = Worksheets("Master List").Cells(x, 1).Value
              End Function
          End If
       End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: That Index formula works great.  I will go through with the macro version as well for practice.  One question, what is the ctrl+shift+enter?  I have never seen that being needed for anything.  I edited the formula to include $'s so that I could drag the formula across several cells and that worked great as well.  Once I did the ctrl+shift+enter on one cell, I could drag it and it would be instantly updated in the others.  Note to others, if you just hit enter, you get the output as "#N/A".  I did that first and thought there was a problem.     Thanks to everyone for the input!!!

Comment: Lookup "Array Formulas". Basically, if you want a formula to return more than 1 value or an array of values, the result of which will get assigned to a cell or cells - one can use array formulas. For e.g. if you have 2 cells (matching your criteria) - you can select say 2 cells, press F2, type in the formula in the 1st cell, press ctrl+shift+enter - you will see that the 1st return value is assigned to 1st cell, 2nd value to the 2nd selected cell. Try it out.